# Search for a pattern while excluding some characters in the input

Tags: javascript, regex

This is a part of bigger problem I'm trying to solve. I'll mention both of them.

Say, with a needle like `bi` and haystack like `Bird`, I could use the following code to search for the needle and apply some formatting to the haystack:

```
const regExp = new RegExp(/bi/, 'gi');
inputStr = inputStr.replace(regExp, '*' + '$&' + '@');
```

The above would mutate the inputStr like: `*Bi@rd` (I'll explain later why I'm formatting.)

**Now, is it possible to search this modified haystack `*Bi@rd` for a needle `ir`?**

Bigger problem I'm trying to solve:
Finding multiple needles in a haystack and highlighting them. 
Needles will come in the form of a space separated string. The haystack is user names, so not very long.

This is one of the solutions I came up with:

```
function highlighter(inputStr, searchQuery) {
  const needles = searchQuery.split(' ');
  let regExp;

  needles.forEach((pattern) => {
    regExp = new RegExp(pattern, 'gi');
    inputStr = inputStr.replace(regExp, '*' + '$&' + '@');
  });

 const highlightedStr = inputStr.replace(/[*]/g, '<span class="h">').replace(/[@]/g, '</span>');
 return highlightedStr;
}
```

My solution will fail if I try to highlight `bi ir` in `Bird`.

I've another solution but it's complicated. So wondering, short of using a library, what's the best way to solve my problem.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand why you need to format the string?

Comment: @XTOTHEL I need to format the string so that I can apply some HTML for highlighting. Eg.: If I've a formatted string like *Bir@d, I could replace all * with <span class='highlight'> and @ with </span>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is, between each character in the needle, use `[`(insertedChars)`]*` to optionally match the characters that might be inserted. For your particular example, the only character inserted *between* the characters is `@`, so to find `ir`, you would use:

```
i[@]*r
```

But there's only one character in that character set, so it reduces to `i@*r`. Example:

```js
const haystack = '*Bi@rd';
const re = /i@*r/i;
console.log(haystack.replace(re, '<<foobar>>'));
```

Another example, for if the inserted characters can be `@`, `#`, or `%`, in a haystack of `qw##e@%rty` with a needle of `wer`:

```js
const haystack = 'qw##e@%rty';
const re = /w[@#%]*e[@#%]*r/i;
console.log(haystack.replace(re, '<<foobar>>'));
```

Also note that if the `searchQuery` items can contain RE special characters, they'll have to be [escaped first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript).

For a dynamic needle, you'll have to insert the character set in between each character programmatically. Using the above example again:

```js
const escape = s => s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');

const haystack = 'qw##e@%rty';
const needle = 'wer';
const inserted = '@#%';
const re = new RegExp(
  escape(needle).replace(/\\?.(?!^)/g, '$&[' + inserted + ']*'),
  'gi'
);

console.log(haystack.replace(re, '<<foobar>>'));
```

Another thing to keep in mind is that rather than concatenating three strings together, you can simply use one large string:

```
inputStr = inputStr.replace(regExp, '*$&@');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a well thought out and thorough answer. Just tested with some input and, this is exactly what I want. I think I can take it from here and refine as I see fit.